# MAYA 2016: Align multiple faces in line

Tags: maya

I want to align selected faces on line(black) so they all would be flat. How can I do this?

[image: Align these faces]

Comment: Usually you just scale them. Also technical 3d questions are mostly out of scope of graphic design

Comment: Select vertices, and drag on the yellow line then hit x down. If this does not work then change the snapping behaviour drom move tool by doubleclicking it and disabling or enabling step snap (dont remember been a good 5 years since i used maya daily). (Alteenative dirty trick if you need to average the vertices or create intermediale edgeloop in one direction scale the point selection by zero)

Comment: I mean x is gridsnap so if you dont want to ise a grid you could also use v and use a vertex as snapping magnet. But really all of this is maya 101 which you should have learned on hour 1.